# Debian 8 : No LSB modules are available

Tags: debian-jessie, lsb

When I run `lsb_release` on Debian 8, following error is appeared:

```
No LSB modules are available.
```

Is there any missing file causes this problem?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As the error message says `lsb_release` command is installed but `lsb` module isn't. Use this command to solve the problem:

```
apt-get install lsb-core
```

I suggest to use `lsb_release -a` instead of `lsb_release`. It shows more useful output.

Comment: This doesn't work on my debian stretch. Any other ideas?

Comment: What is the problem? you can't install lsb-core or running ip causes errors?

Comment: @SuB On Stretch `lsb-compat` is installed instead as replacement for `lsb-core` and after this is installed it changes nothing. `lsb_release -a` still outputs `No LSB modules are available.` (together with the excepted useful output, so it is not really a problem but still irritating).

Comment: On Ubuntu 18 `lsb_release -cs` worked, then it stopped oddly. I installed `lsb-core` and it works like a butterfly, ty.

Answer (score 10):

I just moved to Debian 11, Bullseye and, in order to check the release, you have to type

```
lsb_release -cs
```

`lsb-core` in Bullseye does not exist.

Comment: `lsb_release -r` still works, too, if all you want is the release *number*, or `lsb_release -a` if you want it all. But none of this has anything to do with the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

Debian discontinued support for the *Linux Standard Base* in 2015.
See [Debian and LSB](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianLsb).

If you don't want to see the message *No LSB modules are available*,
a workaround is to use the flags `-cdir` instead of `-a` :

```
lsb_release -cdir
```

Comment: `lsb_release -cdir` still shows mentioned message on my Debian 12, only workaround for me is to use `2>/dev/null`. Anyway, hanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

While building a container image based on Debian 11 (bullseye) I had to install the `lsb_release` command using:

```
apt-get -y install lsb-release
```

since, as Denis Pitzalis pointed out, the `lsb-core` package does not exist for 11